# Partial bytewise access to C enum

Tags: c, enums

**Setting:**

1. I define an enum in C99:

   ```
   enum MY_ENUM {TEST_ENUM_ITEM1, TEST_ENUM_ITEM2, TEST_ENUM_ITEM_MAX};
   ```
2. I ensure with compile time asserts that `TEST_ENUM_ITEM_MAX` does not exceed `UINT16_MAX`. I assume little endian as byte order.
3. I have a serialize-into-buffer function with following parameters:

   ```
   PutIntoBuffer(uint8_t* src, uint32_t count);
   ```
4. I serialize a variable holding an value into a buffer. For this task i access the variable, holding the enum, like this:

   ```
   enum MY_ENUM testVar = TEST_ENUM_ITEM;

   PutIntoBuffer((uint8_t*) &testVar, sizeof(uint16_t));
   ```

**Question:** Is it legitimate to access the enum (which is an int) in this way? Does C standard guarantee the intended behaviour?

Comment: If the enum can be bigger than U8_MAX then it will probably be strange to cast it to U8 pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legitimate as in "it will work if int is 16 bits". It does not violate any pointer aliasing rules either, as long as you use a character type like `uint8_t`. (De-serializing is another story though.)

However, the code is not portable. In case `int` is 32 bit, the enumeration constants will turn 32 bit too, as may the enum variable itself. Then the code will turn endianess-dependent and you might end up reading garbage. Checking TEST_ENUM_ITEM_MAX against UINT16_MAX doesn't solve this.

The proper way to serialize an enum is to use a pre-generated read-only look-up table which is guaranteed to be 8 bits, like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

enum MY_ENUM {TEST_ENUM_ITEM1, TEST_ENUM_ITEM2, TEST_ENUM_ITEM_MAX};

static const uint8_t MY_ENUM8 [] =
{
  [TEST_ENUM_ITEM1] = TEST_ENUM_ITEM1,
  [TEST_ENUM_ITEM2] = TEST_ENUM_ITEM2,
};

int main (void)
{
  _Static_assert(sizeof(MY_ENUM8)==TEST_ENUM_ITEM_MAX, "Something went wrong");
}
```

The designated initializer syntax improves the integrity of the data, should the enum be updated during maintenance. Similarly, the static assert will ensure that the list contains the right number of items.

Comment: In what case do i read garbage for int beeing 32 bit and little endianess? Are values up to UINT16_MAX safe to read?

Comment: @user259819 Ah, garbage (in the form of all zeroes) will only occur with big endian. But anyway, there is no reason to use weird, non-portable pointer tricks when you can get deterministic, portable code that is generated at compile-time.